# apache POI- derived cells are becoming #NA

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache POI, I am trying to fill up an XLSX sheet. This is an insurance premium calculator and has inbuilt formulas. I am able to put desired values in required cells using POI but the derived cells are becoming "#NA". Whenever I do that manually things are working fine. What can go wrong ?

Comment: Did you forget to [re-evaluate the cached formula result values](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with that after you said but still the same error. I have narrowed down one thing. Basically , one particular cell is becoming #NA which has following formula =VLOOKUP(C41,'R'!I19:J24,2). Other cells are dependent on it and so they are also becoming NA. If I can figure out why the VLOOKUP cell is becoming #NA then i think problem will get solved.

Comment: I have figured out more. There is a hidden sheet called 'R'. It has encrypted cells .